# Turn off spell checking for a textbox

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I want to create a textbox with no spell checking when the user use the software keyboard. I have tried this:

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" IsSpellCheckEnabled="False" IsTextPredictionEnabled="False" />
```

But somehow spell checking and still occurs in the software keyboard. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try adding  SpellCheck.IsEnabled="False" .SpellCheck is different class available in dot net framework.

Comment: @PEK its working fine for me on my mobile, it is not checking spelling

Comment: @GaurangDave, SpellCheck.IsEnabled doesn't exists for UWP as I understand it, only WPF :-(

Comment: @ShubhamSahu, you are right that it works as expected for phones. But it doesn't work the same for tablets or computers :-/. You can enable the software keyboard by right clicking on the taskbar.

Comment: @PEK you are partially right i checked on pc also it is not checking spelling but  provides suggestions on on screen keyboard because of system settings